# Error al ejecutar un jnlp JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación desde el **jnlp** me sale este Error, pero cuando lo ejecuto desde el **IDE** no me da problemas.

```
public class AplicacionMipe extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {


    Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/aplicacionmipe/Inicio.fxml"));
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2);
    stage.setScene(scene2);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
```

este es el error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at aplicacionmipe.AplicacionMipe.start(AplicacionMipe.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:134)
    at 

 com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at 
 com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at 
  com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at 
  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:150)
    at 
  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at aplicacionmipe.AplicacionMipe.start(AplicacionMipe.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:134)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Ya has comprobado que la ruta esta bien?.

Comment: Si la ruta estan bien, cuando lo ejecuto en NetBeans no sale el error, pero al momento de ejecutar el archivo jnlp si me muestra ese error

Comment: con el netbeans dando en clean and build el lo genera

Comment: intenta reemplando la ubicacion del archivo con esto getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("applicationmipe/Inicio.fxml")

Comment: Ya le he intentado asi, y no funciona

Comment: Prueba con esto: `AplicacionMipe.class.getClassLoader().getResource("aplicacionmipe/Inicio.fxml")` y recuerda que dentro del jar el fxml debe estar en ese camino...

Comment: Ya lo intente y tampoco me funciona